# Java/Android - AsyncTask execution, trying to run synchronus tasks, unchecked call to "execute(params)"

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I am trying to run two AsyncTask synchronously.

```
AsyncTask task1 = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>() {
//First task here
};

AsyncTask task2 = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>() {
//Second task here
};
```

To underline that the task work perfectly, I tried to place them directly in the function onCreate in the same way:

```
AsyncTask task1 = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>() {
//First task here
}.execute();

AsyncTask task2 = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>() {
//Second task here
}.execute();
```

But the problem is that the tasks start together and not one after the other. So I tried to place them off function onCreate, then recalling them according to this method, so that worked in synchronus:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

task1.execute();
    if(task1.getStatus() == AsyncTask.Status.FINISHED){
        task2.execute();
    }

}
```

Here I get an error from the Android Studio: "Unchecked call to 'execute(Params...)' as a member of raw type 'android.os.AsyncTask'".

What's wrong? how do I fix it? Or what could be another way to work in sync these two tasks?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why don't you just start the second AsyncTask in the `onPostExecute` method of the first AsyncTask?

The unchecked call is probably due to type check. Change your declaration to this:

```
AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> task1 = ...;
AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> task2 = ...;
```

Comment: As you said, I insert the second task in the onPostExecute method. It runs perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

At first let us resolve the question directly, then I will suggest the better solution.

you can do like this to sync run two tasks:

```
AsyncTask task2 = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>() {
    // Second task here
};

AsyncTask task1 = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>() {
    // First task here
    // ...
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        task2.execute();
    }
}.execute();
```

different AsyncTask run in different thread, so you can't ensure their run order and return order. if you want, you should choose Handler better. one Handler handle all message in the same thread and can ensure their run order.

so you can do like this:

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // do task1 things
    }
});
handler.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // do task2 things
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

What API level are you using? On 3.2+ platforms `AsyncTask`s work on the same background thread because they use serial executor. So, if you `execute` multiple `AsyncTask`s they will go to the same queue and they will execute synchronously.

For 1.6-3.2 platforms you can call `executeOnExecutor` and pass your own serial executor there.

Refer: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

See **Order Of Execution**

Answer (score 0):

To synchronize your tasks to run one after the other, you can use the message handler in task1. If task 1 has finished, it will run `onPostExecute` in which you send a message to your handler which in turn executes task2.

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(final Void result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    Message msg = new Message();
    msg.what = 1;
    mHandler.sendMessage(msg);
}
```

Look at an example AsyncTask class:

```
public class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
    private Handler mHandler;
    public MyAsyncTask(Handler mHandler) {
        this.mHandler = mHandler;
    }
}
```

And somewhere in your main class

```
        Handler mHandler = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            switch (msg.what) {
                case 1:
                    task2.execute();
                    break;
            }
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

My thought is, do you even need two AsyncTasks?  In one project I needed to do two tasks, but created a single AsyncTask that called a method to do the first task and then another method to do the second task, all within doInBackground().